# simple SQL not working on table

Tags: sql

Have this odd behavior, was wondering if anyone can help.

Table:

STATUS,TYPE,ID
passed,requirement,J1X11986
passed,requirement,J1X11986-ABC

```
SQL> select id from MY_TABLE;

ID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
J1X11986


SQL> select status from MY_TABLE where id='J1X11986';

no rows selected

SQL> select status from MY_TABLE where id='J1X11986-ABC';

RESULT
------
passed
```

Comment: what's the data type of `id`?, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: VARCHAR2(80) and oracle 11g express

Comment: what happens if you use `WHERE id LIKE '%J1X11986%'`?

Comment: I did try that before i posted this question and yes, it works. However, I need an exact match as 'J1X11986' and 'J1X11986-ABC' are possible entries for 'id' field in this table.

Comment: you must have some non-printable chars in your string.

Comment: bingo. thank you. good bless vi.
stupid windows carriage return '^M'.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a TRIM.  There may be white spaces.

If you are using SQL server use below query.

```
    Select status
      From MyTable
      Where LTRIM (RTRIM (id))='J1X11986'
```

Comment: tried, no luck. also, i dont see any spaces. i have tried moving the cursor with the keyboard to confirm.